# Ошибка при вызове деструктора std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management

Класс CSysError:

```
// error.h
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <memory>

class CError
{
public:
    CError();
    virtual ~CError();

    virtual const TCHAR* description() const = 0;
    unsigned long code() const;

protected:
    unsigned long m_errCode;
};

class CSysError : public CError
{
public:
    CSysError();
    virtual ~CSysError();

    virtual const TCHAR* description() const override;
    DWORD bytesInMsg() const;

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<TCHAR> m_errMsg;
};

// error.cpp

#include "error.h"

CError::CError()
    : m_errCode( 0UL )
{}

CError::~CError()
{}

unsigned long CError::code() const
{
    return m_errCode;
}

CSysError::CSysError()
    : CError()
    , m_errMsg( nullptr )
{
    DWORD dwErrCode = GetLastError();

    HLOCAL pMsgBuf = NULL;
    FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
        , NULL
        , dwErrCode
        , MAKELANGID( LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US )
        , (PTSTR) &pMsgBuf
        , 0
        , NULL );

    if( pMsgBuf != NULL )
    {
        m_errMsg.reset( (TCHAR*) pMsgBuf );
        m_errCode = dwErrCode;
    }
    else
    {
        // LocalFree( pMsgBuf );
    }
}

CSysError::~CSysError()
{}

const TCHAR* CSysError::description() const
{
    return ( m_errMsg ) ? m_errMsg.get() : __TEXT( "" );
}

DWORD CSysError::bytesInMsg() const
{
    if( m_errMsg )
        return HeapSize( GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, m_errMsg.get() );

    return 0UL;
}
```

Проблемное место:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( __TEXT( "C:/Users/isnullxbh/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/winapi/example2.txt" )
        , GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
        , FILE_SHARE_READ
        , NULL
        , OPEN_EXISTING
        , NULL
        , NULL );

    if( (unsigned) hFile == 0xffffffff )
    {
        CSysError sysError;
        const TCHAR* pErrMsg = sysError.description();

        DWORD dwBufSizeInBytes = sysError.bytesInMsg();
        DWORD dwNumCharsForWrite = dwBufSizeInBytes / sizeof( TCHAR );

        DWORD dwWrittenChars = 0;
        WriteConsole( hSTDErr, (LPCVOID) pErrMsg, dwNumCharsForWrite, &dwWrittenChars, NULL );

        if( dwNumCharsForWrite != dwWrittenChars )
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }
```

Когда вызывается деструктор у объекта `sysError` ( класс `CSysError` ) наблюдается неопределенное поведение (если так можно выразится): при release-конфигурации все проходит без ошибок, при debug-конфигурации - наблюдаются проблемы с разрушением `std::shared_ptr` - жалуется на неполный тип `TCHAR`. Что подскажите ?

Call-стек:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, проблема в том, что Вы неправильно работаете с памятью.

Читаем документацию к функции [`FormatMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx):

> lpBuffer [out]
>
> A pointer to a buffer that receives the null-terminated string that specifies the formatted message. If `dwFlags` includes `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`, the function allocates a buffer using the `LocalAlloc` function, and places the pointer to the buffer at the address specified in `lpBuffer`.

Перевод:

> Указатель на буфер, который примет строку, завершающуюся нулём, содержащую форматированное сообщение. Если `dwFlags` содержит `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`, функция размещает буфер, используя функцию `LocalAlloc`, и помещает указатель на буфер по адресу, указанному в `lpBuffer`.

Иными словами, память для строки выделяется функцией `LocalAlloc`, а Вы пихаете указатель на эту память в `std::shared_ptr`, который при разрушении пытается освободить память совершенно другим методом (подозреваю, что это `delete[]`). Естественно, получается неопределённое поведение. Для очистки такой памяти нужно использовать `LocalFree`.

Я бы скопировал полученную строку в `std::string`, которую и передал бы в `std::shared_ptr`, а память немедленно очистил бы посредством `LocalFree`. Или же можно создать свой маленький класс-обёртку, автоматически разрушающую такую строку и передавал бы в `std::shared_ptr` его экземпляр. Например, этот класс может выглядеть так:

```
template<class T> class LocalAllocWrapper {
    private :
        T* p;
    public :
        LocalAllocWrapper(T* _p) : p(_p) {}
        ~LocalAllocWrapper() {
            LocalFree(p);
        }
        T* data() {
            return p;
        }
}
```

Comment: Если класс в деструкторе вызывает `LocalFree`, то наверное для симметрии стоит вызывать `LocalAlloc` в конструкторе?

Comment: FormatMessage сама дергает LocalAlloc,

Comment: Спасибо, отметил. Скажите еще, пожалуйста, если бы FormatMessage дергала не LocalAlloc, а HeapAlloc - было бы все нормально на Ваш взгляд?

Comment: @isnullxbh Я не думаю, что всё было бы нормально. Всё было бы нормально если бы `FormatMessage` дёргала `new[]`, но она этого сделать не может, поскольку `new[]` реализован в прикладной программе, а `FormatMessage` - в системной библиотеке. Всё дело в том, что распределитель памяти в RTL может быть реализован как угодно. Всегда (точнее, почти всегда) есть парные функции выделения/освобождения памяти и их вызовы должны быть скоррелированы.

Comment: @kff, большое спасибо за развернутый ответ )

Comment: @kff, если честно, я думал это работает так: есть таблица дескрипторов объектов ядра, с которыми мы работаем в контексте данного процесса; и почему-то я решил, что если мы вызываем _SomeoneAlloc_ - то в этой же таблице появляется запись о том, что у нас появилось разрешение на чтение/запись стольки-то количесива байт с таким-то стартовым адресом - ну а уж имея такую информацию - вернуть память ОС будет довольно-таки просто.

Comment: @isnullxbh Аллокатор RTL может работать совершенно не так. Например, он может через `VirtualAlloc` получать у ОС блоки большого размера (постранично, например), память внутри которых далее начнёт распределять самостоятельно. Т.е. будет один дескриптор ОС, описывающий страницу, и куча размещённых в этой странице аллокатором переменных. Для своих целей аллокатор может сохранить размер выделенной памяти непосредственно в самой странице (часто размещается перед началом выделенной памяти). P.S. Кстати, `VirtualAlloc` и `LocalFree` тоже нельзя применять совместно.

Comment: @kff, все, теперь все стало на свои места. Спасибо.

Comment: @isnullxbh Да не за что. Рад был помочь.